# "vmstat" says there is paging activity - how to identify the swapping process?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, swap

I have a scenario where I can see there is paging activity on my Ubuntu 16.04 laptop using `vmstat 1 100`.

Due to the sheer size of the current load it is expected that processes are more or less swapped out to disk which is fine. I would, however, like to identify those that cause pages to swapped in *all the time* (as identified by `vmstat`) as this might indicate that memory allocation could be improved.

My sysadmin skills are a bit rusty but I am comfortable in a root shell.

What commands should I use to identify the processes which are causing swapping activity?

Answer (score 1):

With performance problems (e.g. high CPU iowait times) it's generally best to monitor these things *over time* rather than after the fact, especially when short-lived processes might be the culprit. On Linux one tool you can use interactively is [`iotop`](http://guichaz.free.fr/iotop/) (fixed link) (see also the answers to [this question about tracking disk I/O](https://serverfault.com/questions/169676/howto-check-disk-i-o-utilisation-per-process)). You can script this (batch mode) or run it interactively like `top`, use the cursor keys to sort by SWAPIN, or use the `-o` option so the output isn't so cluttered. You will need Python ≥2.7 and various kernel configuration parameters enabled (see `iotop`'s `README` or man page).

Rather than use only data from `/proc` like `vmstat`, `iotop` uses [`taskstats`](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/accounting/taskstats.txt), this uses [netlink IPC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netlink) to efficiently provide process accounting directly from the kernel to user space.

On most flavours of Linux with the default "[swappiness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swappiness)" setting of 60, it's fairly normal to see paging activity when the system is moderately busy: the kernel is pre-emptively writing little-used process pages to swap instead of purging more recently used disk cache pages. (There's a related parameter `vfs_cache_pressure` to tune some cacheing behaviour.) If you observe persistent ongoing paging, then there is likely more to it than just this.

Otherwise, if you are concerned about swap use *right now* rather than over time: the kernel keeps track of swap use per process in `/proc/PID/status`. You can do something quick with `gawk` (≥v4.0):

```
gawk '/^Name:/{nm=$2} /^Pid:/{pid=$2} /^VmSwap:/{sw=$2} 
  ENDFILE{printf("%-24s %6i %6ikiB\n",nm,pid,sw)}' /proc/[0-9]*/status | 
sort -h -k 3
```

According to [the documentation](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html) shmem (shared memory) that's swapped out is not counted here, but you hopefully won't need to care about that. [Eric Ljungstrom's `getswap.sh` script](http://northernmost.org/blog/find-out-what-is-using-your-swap/) can also be used, there's a more advanced version of it in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12254656/1955371).

Comment: Just to be clear - I am not seeing swap usage increased but that apparently _some_ processes are reading in pages all the time.  I want to identify these.  Can iotop do that?

Comment: Yes, it will show swapin (as a %), apologies I linked to the wrong iotop (there are it seems at least four different ones...) Fixed link. The kernel does not "blame" a process for page out, they are not accounted for per PID.

Answer (score -1):

Try the command:

```
 ps -eo pid,cmd,vsz
```

This will list process in the format process id, command executed, and virtual memory size of the process in KiB

Comment: From "man ps":  _vsz         VSZ       virtual memory size of the process in KiB  (1024-byte units).  _  I need the activity, not the total size.  These are page-ins.  The total size will not change.

Comment: You would need to run something like "find /proc -maxdepth 2 -name stat -exec cat '{}' \;" then and parse the output.

Comment: Did you actually try this?